# Can you style HTML input elements filled by browser?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have ASP.NET MVC app with login page:

```
    <form id="account" method="post">
        <h2>Use email account to log in.</h2>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true"/>
            <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating" >
            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-label"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="checkbox form-row">
                <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
```

It uses bootstrap classes. It looks nice with dark theme:

[image]

But once the browser (tried Chrome and Edge) pre-filled the form it becomes ugly and I was told its by design.

Is there any way I can change the pre-filled form elements colours?

[image]

**EDIT:** as suggested I looked up for autofill and found only these:

```
      .form-floating > .form-control:-webkit-autofill {
       padding-top: 1.625rem;
       padding-bottom: .625rem
      }
      .form-floating > .form-select {
       padding-top: 1.625rem;
       padding-bottom: .625rem
      }
      .form-floating > .form-control: not(:-moz-placeholder-shown)~label {
       opacity: .65;
       transform: scale(.85)translateY(-.5rem)translateX(.15rem)
      }
      .form-floating > .form-control: focus~label, .form-floating > .form-control: not(:placeholder-shown)~label, .form-floating > .form-select~label {
       opacity: .65;
       transform: scale(.85)translateY(-.5rem)translateX(.15rem)
      }
      .form-floating > .form-control:-webkit-autofill~label {
       opacity: .65;
       transform: scale(.85)translateY(-.5rem)translateX(.15rem)
      }
```

so I added the following css to override it but it has no effect:

```
.form-floating > .form-control:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #dedede;
    border-color: #2a2a2a;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is Bootstrap 4? [From the document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/) I don't see form floating anywhere.

Comment: its Bootstrap v5.1.3

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill

Comment: thank you.. I tried to override it but it doesnt work (see the edit). any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the style I was looking for is this:

```
.form-control:disabled, .form-control[readonly] {
    background-color: #dedede;
    border-color: #2a2a2a;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

*Thanks to @epascarello and @vee for help*